# Using Join with Group By in Laravel for Count

Tags: php, laravel

we have following tables

[Subjects Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFfjJ.png)
[Students Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo7yZ.png)

We want output like following

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oehb6.png)

**Here is what we have done till now, I mean the query**

```
$enrolledStudents = Student::select('students.subject_id', 'subjects.subject_name as subject_name', DB::raw('count(subject_id) as total'))
        ->leftJoin('subjects', 'subjects.id', '=', 'students.subject_id')
        ->groupBy('students.subject_id')
        ->get();
```

This query is not working,

`Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'subjects.subject_name' isn't in GROUP BY`

what can we do the get the **expected output**

Comment: Can you define *Not working* ? what is the result of this query ? can you add in your post

Comment: added, do check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only columns that are aggregated or present in group by clause, like `subject_name` is not aggregated nor part of group by clause so in strict mode databases will throw this error as this operation is not allowed.

Moreover you should use Subject model as left table for join so that you will get all the subjects even if there are no enrolled students in it

```
Subject::from('subjects as s')
        ->select('s.subject_name', DB::raw('count(s.id) as total'))
        ->leftJoin('students as st', 's.id', '=', 'st.subject_id')
        ->groupBy('s.subject_name')
        ->get();
```

Or if you have defined the relations between your Subject and Student model then you can use `withCount()`

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class, 'subject_id', 'id');
    }
}

Subject::withCount('students')->get();
```

Comment: thanks it worked, and I wish I cound do the second one but have to release the fix today :P

Comment: @MissingSemicolon thats a scary day for devs :) you can plan it after the release, cheers

Comment: one question, how can i get subject_id from subjects table? i tried doing it but i'm getting following error ```Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db.subjects.id' isn't in GROUP BY```

Comment: @MissingSemicolon you need to add `subject_id` in group by also like `select('subject_id','subject_name')` and `groupBy('subject_id','subject_name')`

Answer (score 1):

if you really don't want to group using any other columns you should **set strict to false** in your **config\database.php** file & run **php artisan config:clear and config:cache**

```
    'mysql' => [
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```